# Haskell: modelling online game states for GUI

Tags: haskell, state

I'm writing a client UI for an online game. It is structured as a *Model* module which represents the game state and a *View* module, which keeps track of the current game state and updates it using model transitions, i.e. functions from one state to another. To take advantage of static type checking I've modelled states as distinct types with type classes representing common traits:

```
class Erring s where errors :: s -> [String]
class WithPlayers s where players :: s -> [String]
class Erring s => LoggedIn s

data LoggedOut = LoggedOut [String] deriving (Eq, Show)
instance Erring LoggedOut where errors (LoggedOut es) = es

data Ready = Ready [String] [String] deriving (Eq, Show)
instance Erring Ready where errors (Ready _ es) = es
instance LoggedIn Ready
instance WithPlayers Ready where players (Ready ps _) = ps

data NotReady = NotReady [String] [String] deriving (Eq, Show)
instance Erring NotReady where errors (NotReady _ es) = es
instance LoggedIn NotReady
instance WithPlayers NotReady where players (NotReady ps _) = ps

-- some transitions:

login :: String -> LoggedOut -> Either Ready LoggedOut
login pwd (LoggedOut es) = 
  if pwd == "password" then Left $ Ready [] es
  else Right $ LoggedOut (es ++ ["incorrect password"])

logout :: LoggedIn s => s -> LoggedOut
logout s = LoggedOut $ errors s
```

This can be a bit tedious when there are dozens of states and instances to define but results in a robust API.

Enter the View. For storing the state I wanted to use a `TMVar`, so that both the UI thread and the thread processing messages from the server can execute state transitions. Since each state is a different type I created a new type that can represent every possible state:

```
data SessionState = SSLoggedOut LoggedOut
                  | SSReady Ready
                  | SSNotReady NotReady
```

And can now define the state reference of type `TMVar SessionState`.

Now, this doesn't feel quite right. I effectively have to define each state twice, once as a type, the other time as type constructor wrapping this type. So, questions:

1. Is it reasonable to model the game state in this way?
2. Is it reasonable to keep the state value in a `TMVar` if atomic updates by different threads are a requirement or is there a better way of keeping track of the state?
3. If `TMVar` is the right way, is it then necessary to have something like `SessionState` wrapper defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a minute to understand why `LoggedIn` is a class when `LoggedOut` is data, but ...

1. Yes, I think it is a reasonable model.
2. Yes, `TVar` is the best way to do this afaik. I assume you know about the combinator [`atomically`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/stm/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-STM.html#v%3aretry)
3. Yes, afaik. See next paragraph.

If you want the type checking *and* the synchronizing TMVar, then you need to define both the types (for type checking) and the data wrapper (for the TMVar). I see no way around it; to my knowledge, a TMVar must remain the same type. (correct me if I'm wrong!)

If it were me, I would drop the types, and instead use functions and guards.

```
data SessionState = Ready {errors :: [String], players :: [String]}
                  | NotReady {errors :: [String], players :: [String]}
                  | LoggedOut {errors :: [String]}
                  deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)

loggedIn :: SessionState -> Bool
loggedIn (LoggedOut _) = False
loggedIn _             = True

ready :: SessionState -> Bool
ready (Ready _ _) = True
ready _           = False

addError :: SessionState -> String -> SessionState
addError s e = s {errors = e:errors s}

addPlayer :: SessionState -> String -> SessionState
addPlayer s@(LoggedOut _) p = addError s $ "Can't add " ++ p ++ " when logged out"
addPlayer s p               = s {players = p:players s}
```

Here are some simple functions you might use to move from one state to another. I tried to give examples both using guards and using pattern matching; you can pick which style you like better or mix it up like I did:

```
login :: SessionState -> SessionState
login (LoggedOut es) = NotReady es []
login s              = addError s "Can't log in when already logged in"

logout :: SessionState -> SessionState
logout s
    | loggedIn s = LoggedOut $ errors s
    | otherwise  = addError s "Can't log out when not logged in"

enable :: SessionState -> SessionState
enable (NotReady es ps) = Ready es ps
enable s@(LoggedOut _)  = addError s "Can't enable when logged out"
enable s@(Ready _ _ )   = addError s "Can't enable when already ready"

disable :: SessionState -> SessionState
disable s
    | ready s   = NotReady (errors s) (players s)
    | otherwise = addError s "Can't disable when not ready"
```

And a dumb example function that uses the `loggedIn` function:

```
countPlayers :: SessionState -> (SessionState, Maybe Int)
countPlayers s
    | loggedIn s = (s, Just . length $ players s)
    | otherwise  = (addError s "Can't count players whilst logged out", Nothing)
```

This approach would have less type safety via the compiler, but can still be very readable, and as added benefit, flexible. Here's me fiddling around in ghci:

```
*Main> LoggedOut []
LoggedOut {errors = []}
*Main> login it
NotReady {errors = [], players = []}
*Main> enable it
Ready {errors = [], players = []}
*Main> addError it "Illegal somethingorother"
Ready {errors = ["Illegal somethingorother"], players = []}
*Main> logout it
LoggedOut {errors = ["Illegal somethingorother"]}
*Main> disable it
LoggedOut {errors = ["Can't disable when not ready","Illegal somethingorother"]}
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. That's exactly how I have implemented it on the first take, but then, having encountered a couple of genuine runtime errors due to functions having been applied to a wrong form of `SessionState`, hoped I could use the type system more. Your comment suggests it might be better to stick to the inital model and trade coding convenience for runtime errors; I'll think about that.

Comment: Also, thanks for `s {errors = e:errors s}` -- I didn't know about this advantage of record syntax, makes using single type for session state even more appealing from the coding perspective.

Comment: Like I said, though you can't use the type system as a safety net against using the wrong `SessionState`, you *can* use guards in much the same way. Just be explicit about what each function depends on. Guards are a good way of expressing [preconditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-condition). I'm relatively new to Haskell, so take everything I say with a grain of salt ;)